# Disabling repeated clicks on an anchor

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript (not jQuery), is there a way of preventing a link from triggering an event more than once?

I'm iterating through some anchors and attaching an onclick event to each link, which then reveals some page content relevant to that link from a json file. The only problem is that a double click or repeated clicks outputs the same content again and again.

What's the best approach to prevent this, or should I re-write the script and change the anchors to submit buttons in order to add a disabled state?

Comment: you can disable the anchor tag once it's clicked

Comment: I suppose you can alter/remove the `href` attribute from the links on first click.

Comment: use events and unbind the click event on click.

Comment: @FelixKling I was thinking abt it too, but looks like no jQuery

Comment: @Arun: Oh... I missed the `not`. Deleting my comment. @Andrew: There are a couple of ways: Removing the event handler or setting a flag and testing it inside the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the event listener after it is clicked first.

```
var element = document.getElementById("id_name");
element.addEventListener("click", onClickHandeler, false);

function onClickHandeler(e) {
    // Do here what your code have to do
   element.removeEventListener("click", onClickHandeler, false);
}
```

Hope this helps you